# Laravel ajax catch 500 Internal server error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel with ajax, and in my controller I have a try - catch block:

```
try {
        something...
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'message'=> 'error message'
        ]);
    }
```

I am using this to show the error message in a div on the page.

This is working, but not if the error is a 500 - internal server error (example: tokenmismatchexception).

Then the error is not caught by the catch-block, and essentially the user is not notified of any error (other than in the console).

Is there a way I can catch such errors, and display an error in the same div as I usually do?

Comment: you catch that in error callback of your ajax in your JS

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was actually it :)

Comment: There is not enough data to answer your question. If you are catch exception and return something, I'm bet laravell will return 200 HTTP status. In case if error was not catched (was thrown outside of your controller) server should send 500 status. So, please check what is actual response (headers and content) and then write client part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because you might not have included the error section.
Make your jQuery Ajax code like:

```
    $.ajax({
        url     : '/yoururl',
        method    : 'POST',
        data    :
        {
            name:"test"
        },
        success   : function(response)
        {
           //USE THIS SECTION WHEN ITS SUCCESS
        },
        error : function(e)
        {
          //SHOW ERROR TO USER HERE THIS SECTION IS CALLED IN CASE OF ERRORS TO SEE THE OBJECT OF the error use console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That is almost embarrassing, but thanks a lot :) I had only used success with if(data.status === "error") and if (data.status === "success")

Comment: People often miss or deliberately do not use the error section..
This should always be used. An Upvote because its an important question.